# If, on 12 December, the House of Commons passes, by a simple majority, a vote of "no confidence" in Theresa May's government, what happens next?

Tags: united-kingdom

At one time the answer would have been simple - a general elction would have ensued.

However under the *Fixed-term Parliaments Act* a two-thirds majority is required to trigger a general election.

It is my understanding that a different government has to be installed within 14 days. In the present circumstances is there any order of priority in which the Queen would call potential Prime Ministers to the Palace? Would it have to begin with the Leader of the Opposition?

Comment: While a vote of no confidence [could happen](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2018/nov/25/labour-plays-waiting-game-over-second-brexit-referendum-corbyn) if the vote on the Brexit deal fails, it's not a given - so the question is currently somewhat hypothetical. So, are you asking what happens if the Brexit deal is rejected, or is this a more general question on what happens if a government loses a confidence vote?

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff If the Withdrawal deal is rejected, two weeks today -11 December- as most observers currently expect will happen, it would seem quite likely to me that the Opposition would put down a motion of no confidence. (If a government has been defeated on its most important policy, how can it be avoided). Of course the Conservative rebels and the DUP could come to TM's aid and ensure she survives the vote of confidence (that raises different questions about what might happen next). But my concern here is as to what happens if the government is defeated.

Comment: It is unlikely that Tory MPs voting against the Brexit deal would also vote for a motion of no confidence, because they have nothing to gain from doing that. A GE won't help them, they would prefer May to either continue and get a better deal or to have an internal Tory leadership contest. A GE simply risks them losing seats and Labour gaining power.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as off-topic because it relates to predicting the fall out of a possible future event.

Comment: @DrunkCynic My understanding is that asking what the rules governing the situation are is on topic, speculation on what events will occur in the grey areas is off topic. I'm not sure if there's a duplicate to the priority question.

Comment: @DrunkCynic the question could be rephrased to remove the date references. What happens following a vote of no-confidence with respect to the 14 day period and who is able to attempt to win a follow on confidence vote seems a good one. There is no need for it to be tied specifically to the Brexit Deal vote, but that is the most obvious current trigger event.

Comment: Can I suggest changing the title to "What happens if a UK Government loses a vote of no confidence?"? The procedure is roughly the same whatever the circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

In the event of a vote of no confidence a government has 14 days to win another one. It can be the same government that lost, or any group of MPs that commands enough of a majority to win a motion of confidence. If they can do so then they may continue governing, if not a general election is automatically triggered.

This was all by convention prior to 2011, when the Fixed Term Parliament Act wrote it into law.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motions_of_no_confidence_in_the_United_Kingdom
http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2011/14/enacted
https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/60641/cabinet-manual.pdf#page=22

Comment: That should be *a* government, not *the* government (that is to say, the new government doesn't have to contain any of the members of the previous one).

Comment: I think "the" is correct, because it's not like the opposition could just say "okay, we are in charge now, we are having a confidence vote and will then govern". The government that lost the vote, as an institution, is the one that can select new leaders and ministers by whatever mechanism the party/coalition has.

Comment: Umm, I think they could, provided they could produce a working coalition to win the vote. That's kind of the whole point of the 14 days. Of course, the current Labour Party seat share is probably too small to make this workable right now.

Comment: The law specifically requires a motion that "the House has confidence in Her Majesty's Government", which implies the one that was formed and recognized after the last election. How would the opposition become Her Majesty's Government without a GE? http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2011/14/enacted

Comment: By being recognised by the Crown (through having a leader  called to the palace as someone who holds the confidence of parliament and will thus be PM) and parliament (by winning the vote of confidence). https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-46288429

Comment: He says that but doesn't explain on what basis or whose authority Labour should be "allowed to try". It seems like the Tories would have to give them the opportunity, or perhaps the Queen could recognize them but that's very unclear from a constitutional point of view.

Comment: Also what is the down-vote about?

Comment: The basis is convention, as with so much of the UK constitution, but this is discussed in section 2.19 of the cabinet manual. I wasn't the down vote, but I suspect it was someone slightly violently disagreeing that only the current party could continue in government without a general election. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/60641/cabinet-manual.pdf#page=22

Comment: @origimbo It is somewhat academic, since clearly it would not seem possible for the Labour Party to win a vote of confidence without a general election first. But the question arises as to whether anyone in the present House of Commons could win one. One possibility could, I suppose be that Theresa May is able to write a new manifesto around which a large body of Labour MPs felt able to gather.

Comment: It seems that there are enough Brexit-skeptic MPs to form a majority just to vote on that one issue, say cancelling Article 50 or entering the EEA, and then call a GE afterwards. A little bit underhanded perhaps, but given the lack of available time it might be a good option for avoiding a crash out which almost no-one wants.

Comment: @user The problem with that is that a House of Commons majority by itself is insufficient to overturn an Act of Parliament. And Article 50 was triggered by an Act. The only way to overturn it would be another Act - which would take weeks to arrange. Otherwise the fact of our leaving the EU on 29 March remains "the law", however many Commons votes to the contrary take place. However, the EU might very well be agreeable to extending the deadline.

Comment: @WS2 There has to be time to pass an Act for the transition period before we crash out, and in fact the vote passing that into law is scheduled for December 12th. It seems like there is plenty of time, at least to pass an extension Act.

Comment: @user But it would seem to me that it might need to be passed into law before 29 March. After that date we will, technically, be out of the EU, and the capacity to rescind Article 50 no longer applicable. And before such a process could be started, there would presumably have to be a change of government.

Comment: @WS2 sure, but how long do you think it takes to do all that? Not nearly four months... It could happen almost immediately in fact.

Comment: @user You can't pass an Act of Parliament in five minutes. There have to be three readings, a committee stage and a report stage in both houses. But first there would have to be a general election, and it is unlikely that could now happen before February.

Comment: @origimbo More in general than in the specific case, it could happen as the result of a by-election.  However, since Labour would need 69 more seats to get a majority, or 34 more if they make an arrangement with the SNP, such a scenario is indeed not current.

Comment: @gerrit At the moment a heavily-whipped "anti-confidence front" has potentially 308 seats - Labour 257, SNP 35, LibDem 12, Plaid Cymru 4. To win a majority it only needs 321 (allowing for the Speaker and Sinn Fein, who do not vote). So on that basis Labour would only have to take 13 seats off the Conservatives, and other things remain equal for a no-confidence motion to succeed. And that is assuming that there were no Tories prepared to vote against the whip - Anna Soubry? Sarah Woolaston? Dominic Grieve? Phillip Lee?

Answer (score 3):

> In the present circumstances is there any order of priority in which the Queen would call potential Prime Ministers to the Palace?

This is answered in the [Cabinet Manual](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/60641/cabinet-manual.pdf) mentioned in user's answer. Some relevant quotes:

> In modern times the convention has been that the Sovereign should not be drawn into party politics, and if there is doubt it is the responsibility of those involved in the political process, and in particular the parties represented in Parliament, to seek to determine and communicate clearly to the Sovereign who is best placed to be able to command the confidence of the House of Commons. As the Crown’s principal adviser this responsibility falls especially on the incumbent Prime Minister, who at the time of his or her resignation may also be asked by the Sovereign for a recommendation on who can best command the confidence of the House of Commons in his or her place.

...

> Under the Fixed-term Parliaments Act 2011, if a government is defeated on a motion that ‘this House has no confidence in Her Majesty’s Government’, there is then a 14-day period during which an alternative government can be formed from the House of Commons as presently constituted, or the incumbent government can seek to regain the confidence of the House. If no government can secure the confidence of the House of Commons during that period, through the approval of a motion that ‘this House has confidence in Her Majesty’s Government’, a general election will take place.

...

> Where a range of different administrations could be formed, discussions may take 
>   place between political parties on who should form the next government.

In other words, it is the responsibility of the outgoing Prime Minister to recommend to the Queen who she should invite to form a new government. The PM's recommendation may be delayed until any discussions within and between parties have made some progress.

This happened (albeit under different circumstances) in 2010, when Gordon Brown stayed on as PM for a few days after losing the election, until it became clear that the Conservatives and Lib Dems were about to form a coalition with a majority in the Commons.

Comment: It's worth adding that the most prominent example of uncertainty as to who should be called to form a government when an existing PM resigned occurred when McMillan stood aside to due ill health. The archaic procedures the Conservative party had for selecting a leader meant he had no clear successor. In the end the problem was resolved when the Queen acted on McMillan's suggestion and asked Alec Douglas-Home (then Lord Home) to form a government.